# Adding default Columns Automatically with Code First Migrations using Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have an requirement to add default columns to the models when i run the migration. for example: i have created a model before migration. I am using .net core v3.1

```
using DataLayer.DataContext;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    [Table("TodoItem", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class TodoItem : ModalBase
    {
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(50)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
        public string EName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Department")]
        public string EDept { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now i want my model to be as like below after migration. i need to do this for all the Models/entities available in the application. it should be automated. it should provide the default columns dynamically when i run the migration.

```
using DataLayer.DataContext;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    [Table("TodoItem", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class TodoItem : ModalBase
    {
         //default column which has to be added to this model after i run migration
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName ="varchar(50)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
        public string EName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Department")]
        public string EDept { get; set; }

         //default column which has to be added to this model after i run migration
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
        [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
        public string IsActive { get; set; }

         //default column which has to be added to this model after i run migration
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
        [Display(Name = "IsDeleted")]
        public string IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The default columns need to be created on DB tables. can anyone help me with a working example would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you just need to run two commands in the Package Management Console.
1) Add-Migration command
2) Update-Database

For example, Add-Migration TodoItem
then Update-Database

If you want to reverse the migration then use the below command:
Remove-Migration

Comment: This is not about the migration commands. i am looking an working example where the default columns to be added every time i run migration on my models and it needs to create tables with the default columns. for example: check this link it will give an idea what i am looking. [link]https://andy.mehalick.com/2014/02/06/ef6-adding-a-created-datetime-column-automatically-with-code-first-migrations/